# Why is the origin header sent for same-origin requests?

Tags: http, http-headers, cors

According to https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#origin-header :

> The `Origin` header is a version of the `Referer` header that does not reveal a path. It is used for all HTTP fetches whose request’s response tainting is "cors", as well as those where request’s method is neither `GET` nor `HEAD`. Due to compatibility constraints it is not included in all fetches.

As I understand it, in particular, the `Origin` header should be sent with any same-origin request except `GET` and `HEAD` methods. How the `Origin` header can be useful in this same-origin case? And why the exception is made for the `GET` and `HEAD` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can help as an CSRF mitigation. So you know your own site made the POST. Using `Origin` as a CSRF mitigation was an afterthought and since it was already deployed for CORS usage, some servers got confused when it was added for `GET` (at least), which is why it's not included there.